# Is it possible to simultaneously view two parts of the same file RStudio?

Tags: rstudio

This is purely and IDE question.  I have been using `emacs` and `ess` for my code development, but am interested in trying out `RStudio`.

One major hesitation is the fact that I have yet to figure out how to get `RStudio` to display two parts of the same file within a column. [image: Example of Emacs Set Up]

Is there a way to do this in R studio?  I've tried adding a second `source` column, but I can't find a way to either

a. Split it

b. Have it display a file that's already being
displayed.

Is this possible?  If so how?

Comment: Your question seems to be more related to technical aspect of `RStudio` software, so you will have more chance of getting an answer on https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've done so.